# Possible to have both modern standby and normal sleep?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, sleep

I currently have modern standby enabled. If I shut my laptop lid or click sleep from the start menu (Windows), the computer doesn't actually go to sleep and I can "wake" it easily by touching the touchpad. This is useful; however it hogs battery when I travel and sometimes the fan doesn't stop.

Is it possible to have both modern standby and normal sleep? For example, if I shut the lid on my laptop, I want modern standby to be enabled so it quickly switches on if I open the lid again. BUT, if I explicitly click sleep from the start menu, I want it to go into normal sleep and not turn on until I press the power button. Is something like that achievable?

Comment: Probably disable Hibernation, OR, something wrong with the OS. Suspend does not shut off a computer in a normally operating computer.

Comment: @John oops I think I didn't phrase my question properly - updated now and hopefully that makes more sense! Thanks for your input

Comment: I don’t think you can have 2 different standbies at the same time. Just use normal standby which recovers very quickly

Comment: Does regular (traditional) suspend mode not wake up on lid-open on your machine? I've had laptops that required a power button press to wake, but it's more common to automatically wake up from S3 sleep when the lid opens (and often it happens fast enough that it's already woken up in the time it takes to fully open the lid). Just like they used to work before S0ix "Modern standby" even became a thing...

Comment: @user1686 Yeah for some reason my laptop doesn't wake up from traditional suspend unless I press the power. I don't mind that but it does take time to recover. However, it's nice in that it won't randomly start in a bag an overheat, hence my hope for both settings. Maybe it's not possible :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state, "my laptop doesn't wake up from traditional suspend unless I press the power." That seems more like the behavior for Hibernate, not Sleep. Sleep should resume in just a few seconds, also.

To be sure it's not actually Hibernating, as Administrator, enter `powercfg -h off` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the CMD prompt to disable Hibernate. Now try Sleep; the PC should wake almost immediately with any key press. Use `powercfg -h on` to allow Hibernation again.

Of course, [there is a difference](https://www.maketecheasier.com/shut-down-vs-sleep-vs-hibernate/) in power usage:

- Hibernate writes the current machine state to disk (i.e., serializes RAM) and then fully shuts down, using *no* power.
- Sleep puts the PC in a low power state, continually demanding a trickle of energy from the battery.

For me, a convenient setting is to allow Sleep when on battery after 15 minutes undisturbed, but to Hibernate if the PC is untouched for 90 minutes, saving the battery charge:

[image: Some Sleep settings]